# Is it possible to get a Tooltip when hovering over one Cell in a JFace TreeViewer

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, tooltip, jface

I have a `TreeViewer` with three columns. The first column shows the name of an element, the second one property and in the third I would like to display an icon if another property is filled and show that property's content in a tooltip on mouseover, as the property is too much text to display it in the `TreeViewer`.
There seems to be no `ITableLabelProvider` equivalent for ToolTips so that I could return a tooltip just for my third column.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot available?

Comment: No, I don't have that source code any longer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tooltip support is available in [`CellLabelProvider`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/CellLabelProvider.html) and its subclasses. Note that cell label providers are set to columns (like [`TreeViewerColumn`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/TreeViewerColumn.html)) and not viewers.
[`ColumnViewerToolTipSupport.enableFor(ColumnViewer viewer)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ColumnViewerToolTipSupport.html) is used to configure tooltips for a viewer.

Comment: Thank you. I totally missed that I could create TreeViewerColumns because up to now, the ITableLabelProvider methods with the column index where enough.